# Why every text shows on img hover when using v-if, v-else, @mouseover and @mouseleave in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to create a hover effect on images with Vue.js. I wrote the following code, but now as I hover over one of the images, the text shows up over all the images.
How can I resolve this problem? I want only the text that belongs to the image I hovered over to appear. Thank you in advance for your help.

Vue template:

```
<template>
<div class="row partner-body-row">
        <div class="col">
          <div
            class="img-wrapper"
            @mouseover="showText = true"
            @mouseleave="showText = false"
          >
            <img
              class="hover-img"
              src="img/img-1"
              alt="img-1"
            />
            <span v-if="showText">Text 1</span>
          </div>
        </div>
<div class="col">
          <div
            class="img-wrapper"
            @mouseover="showText = true"
            @mouseleave="showText = false"
          >
            <img
              class="hover-img"
              src="img/img-2"
              alt="img-2"
            />
            <span v-if="showText">Text 2</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div
            class="img-wrapper"
            @mouseover="showText = true"
            @mouseleave="showText = false"
          >
            <img
              class="hover-img"
              src="img/img-3"
              alt="img-3"
            />
            <span v-if="showText">Text 3</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
     <div class="col">
          <div
            class="img-wrapper"
            @mouseover="showText = true"
            @mouseleave="showText = false">
            <img
              class="hover-img"
              src="img/img-4"
              alt="img-4"
            />
            <span v-if="showText">Text 4</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      showText: false,
    };
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all the conditions are tied to the same variable, have that variable hold each image's number rather than just true/false.

and ideally this should be done in CSS using `:hover`

```
<template>
<div class="row partner-body-row">
        <div class="col">
          <div
            class="img-wrapper"
            @mouseover="showText = 1"
            @mouseleave="showText = 0"
          >
            <img
              class="hover-img"
              src="img/img-1"
              alt="img-1"
            />
            <span v-if="showText === 1">Text 1</span>
          </div>
        </div>
<div class="col">
          <div
            class="img-wrapper"
            @mouseover="showText = 2"
            @mouseleave="showText = 0"
          >
            <img
              class="hover-img"
              src="img/img-2"
              alt="img-2"
            />
            <span v-if="showText === 2">Text 2</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div
            class="img-wrapper"
            @mouseover="showText = 3"
            @mouseleave="showText = 0"
          >
            <img
              class="hover-img"
              src="img/img-3"
              alt="img-3"
            />
            <span v-if="showText === 3">Text 3</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        
     <div class="col">
          <div
            class="img-wrapper"
            @mouseover="showText = 4"
            @mouseleave="showText = 0">
            <img
              class="hover-img"
              src="img/img-4"
              alt="img-4"
            />
            <span v-if="showText === 4">Text 4</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</template>

export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      showText: 0,
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any simpler solution? I have to write a new variable for every img?  What if I go through the variables with foreach?

Comment: updated with a simpler solution, have showText hold the number of the image hovered, and 0 when nothing is hovered, rather than a binary true false which doesn't fit multiple states.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a component for each Image with tooltip, something like:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const Img = {
  name: 'Img',
  props: ['src'],
  data() {
    return { showText: false }
  },
  template: '<div><img @mouseover="showText = true" @mouseleave="showText = false":src="src" /><span v-if="showText">Tooltip</span></div>',
};

const App = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  components: { Img },
  template: '<div><Img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/><Img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/></div>',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's only to show the text on hover. You don't need to use v-model. in this case you would use css.

You could remove all the `v-if's` from the `<span>` and add this css

```
  .image-container span {
     display: 'none';
  }

  .image-container:hover span {
    display: 'block';
  }
```